# How minimize this mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I select photo by id and next photo by order field.

I check the existence of the photo id = 33 and find next photo by order

```
SELECT `id` FROM `product_photo` 
WHERE 
`product_id` = (SELECT `product_id` FROM `product_photo` WHERE `id` = '33' ) 
AND 
`order` >= (SELECT `order` FROM `product_photo` WHERE `id` = '33' ) 
LIMIT 2
```

whether it is possible to simplify this query?

Comment: And your approach is..?

Comment: SELECT id FROM product_photo WHERE id = 33

Comment: @Andrew: Your interpretation is wrong. The query returns all ids where the product_id and order is same as that of id=33. there can be multiple other columns which are different, only the product_photo and order are same

Comment: OMG! Need check existence of the photo by id (33) and find next photo by order.

Comment: @Nadeem> Yes, i know, that's why i didn't post it as an answer. Without knowing full situation it's hard to give specific solution @spat.ne.hochu> If you want clean and simple sql, don't use conditional logic on this level. Do conditional comparison in your application level (php or smth like that). Then you will have simplified query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ever heard of [`JOIN`ing tables](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)?

```
SELECT photo.id
FROM product_photo
INNER JOIN product_photo AS photo ON photo.product_id = product_photo.product_id
   AND photo.order >= product_photo.order
WHERE product_photo.id = '33';
```

The `FROM` and `WHERE` parts will select your product `id = 33` and then you join `product_photo` with different alias (yes, you can join the same table multiple times  in one query) based on `product_id` and `order`.

Comment: I've heard of JOINing tables, but it took me a second to confirm if a self-join would do the trick.

Comment: It's a cool option! Thank you!